# How to select distinct rows from a table without a primary key

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to show a Notification on user login if there is any unread messages. So if multiple users send (5 messages each) while the user is in offline these messages should be shown on login. Means have to show the last messages from each user.

I use joining to find records.

In this scenario Message from User is not a primary key.

This is my query

```
SELECT 
   UserMessageConversations.MessageFrom,  UserMessageConversations.MessageFromUserName,
   UserMessages.MessageTo, UserMessageConversations.IsGroupChat, 
   UserMessageConversations.IsLocationChat, 
   UserMessageConversations.Message, UserMessages.UserGroupID,UserMessages.LocationID 
FROM    
   UserMessageConversations 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   UserMessages ON UserMessageConversations.UserMessageID = UserMessages.UserMessageID 
WHERE
   UserMessageConversations.MessageTo = 743  
   AND UserMessageConversations.ReadFlag = 0
```

This is the output obtained from above query.

[image]

MessageFrom -582 appears twice. I need only one record of this user.

How is it possible

Comment: Both records are different in the 'message' field. How will you decide which one is to be shown? Also, please post your table structure and sample data. Thanks.

Comment: But those are two separate rows because they contain two separate messages. You need to tell us how you determine "distinct" because those aren't distinct to me. When all other columns are the same, do you care which message you get? Is there any reason to even include the message in the query then?

Comment: Ya i know Distinct not working because of the message column.I need to show last message and the count of unread messages.I just mean disctinct for the Messagefrom column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I totally understand your question - but one approach would be to use a CTE (Common Table Expression).

With this CTE, you can partition your data by some criteria - i.e. your `MessageFrom` - and have SQL Server number all your rows starting at 1 for each of those partitions, ordered by some other criteria - this is the point that's entirely unclear from your question, whether you even care what the rows for each `MessageFrom` number are sorted on (do you have some kind of a `MessageDate` or something that you could order by?) ...

So try something like this:

```
;WITH PartitionedMessages AS
(
   SELECT 
      umc.MessageFrom,  umc.MessageFromUserName,
      um.MessageTo, umc.IsGroupChat, 
      umc.IsLocationChat, 
      umc.Message, um.UserGroupID, um.LocationID ,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY umc.MessageFrom
                        ORDER BY MessageDate DESC) AS 'RowNum' <=== totally unclear yet
   FROM    
      dbo.UserMessageConversations umc
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      dbo.UserMessages um ON umc.UserMessageID = um.UserMessageID 
   WHERE
       umc.MessageTo = 743  
       AND umc.ReadFlag = 0
)
SELECT 
    MessageFrom,  MessageFromUserName, MessageTo, 
    IsGroupChat, IsLocationChat, 
    Message, UserGroupID, LocationID 
FROM 
   PartitionedMessages
WHERE
   RowNum = 1
```

Here, I am selecting only the "first" entry for each "partition" (i.e. for each `MessageFrom`) - ordered by a "imagined" `MessageDate` column so that the most recent (the newest) message would be selected.

Does that approach what you're looking for??

Answer (score 0):

If you think of them as same rows, I assume you don't care about the message field.
In this case you can use the `DISTINCT` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   UserMessageConversations.MessageFrom,  UserMessageConversations.MessageFromUserName,
   UserMessages.MessageTo, UserMessageConversations.IsGroupChat, 
   UserMessageConversations.IsLocationChat, 
   UserMessages.UserGroupID,UserMessages.LocationID 
FROM    
   UserMessageConversations 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   UserMessages ON UserMessageConversations.UserMessageID = UserMessages.UserMessageID 
WHERE
   UserMessageConversations.MessageTo = 743  
   AND UserMessageConversations.ReadFlag = 0
```

In general with distinct clause you have a row for every distinct group of row attributes.
If your requirement instead is to show a single field for all the messages (example: every message folded in a single message with a separator between them) you can use an aggregate function, but in SQL Server it seems is [not that easy.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190678.aspx)